# winsock server not accepting connections

Tags: c++, winsock

I have a simple TCP server app that is not accepting any connections.
It is curently built using vs 2019, but was originally built (a while ago) with vs 2012.
The original version works but the 2019 version never accepts.
What areas can I look into?
I do not have access to the client code.
Here is my sever code

```
  int iResult;
   WSADATA wsaData;
   // Initialize Winsock
   iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
   if (iResult != 0) {
      printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
      return 1;
   }
#define DEFAULT_PORT "8082"

   struct addrinfo* result = NULL, * ptr = NULL, hints;

   ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
   hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
   hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
   hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
   hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

   // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
   iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
   if (iResult != 0) {
      printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
      WSACleanup();
      return 1;
   }

   SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

   ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

   if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
      printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
      freeaddrinfo(result);
      WSACleanup();
      return 1;
   }

   iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
   if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
      printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
      freeaddrinfo(result);
      closesocket(ListenSocket);
      WSACleanup();
      return 1;
   }
   printf("bound\n");
   if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
      printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
      closesocket(ListenSocket);
      WSACleanup();
      return 1;
   }

   SOCKET ClientSocket;

   ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

   // Accept a client socket
   ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
   if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
      printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
      closesocket(ListenSocket);
      WSACleanup();
      return 1;
   }

   printf("connected\n");
```

This is the wireshark output
[image]

and this is from netsat
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error, if so, what is it?

Comment: What address and port are you binding to?

Comment: There is no error - just waits for connection

Comment: port is 8082 address is any

Comment: So it's the listen function that doesn't return? Have you tried using netstat -a -n to see if your socket is open and bound?

Comment: netstat -an shows the socket open and listening

Comment: it is the call to accept that never returns

Comment: Are you sure the client sends connection request to that particular port?

Comment: According to wireshark I can see them

Comment: @Gunner The code shown is fine, in so far as opening a listening socket and accepting a connection on it. The problem has to be with the client not connecting to the proper IP/port. On the other hand, this code is only creating 1 listening socket, but `getaddrinfo()` returns a linked lists of addresses, so it is *possible* that the linked list contains multiple local IP addresses (which you don't check for) and the client is trying to connect to an IP that you are simply not creating a listening socket for. What does the output of `netstat` actually say, and what does Wireshark actually show?

Comment: @o_weisman `listen()` doesn't block. Strange question.

Comment: @o_weisman It is the accept that never gets a connection

Comment: See edit for output from wireshark and netstat

Comment: @user207421 From the MSDN documentation: "Note  When issuing a blocking Winsock call such as listen, Winsock may need to wait for a network event before the call can complete."

Comment: @o_weisman I know what it says, but it doesn't block. There is nothing for it to block on. It doesn't do any I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue
It was the firewall stopping the connection requests